# Not able to run large dynamic select query in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure which is executing a dynamic select query. The query string is large. The following is the stored procedure

```
create or replace
procedure My_SP
(
procRefCursor out sys_refcursor,
--My other input variables here
)
is

dynSqlComplete varchar2(8000) := 'n/a';

begin

  dynSqlComplete := 'Large query here';

  open procRefCursor for dynSqlComplete;

end;
```

When I run this sp it shows the following error

> **ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qcscbAddToSelLists], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []**

so I reduced the size of `dynSqlComplete` variable to varchar2(5000) and then ran the stored procedure. I got the following error:

> **ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small**

I have tried many things in vain and also I do not want to add them here because it will misguide.

**-- EDIT -- 6 Jun 2012**

Hi All,

I was able to pin point the problem but I am not yet able to solve it. I tried to run the query part by part and I found the query which was throwing an error. It contained `START WITH` and when i commented it the query started to work. I have given the code below and commented out the code which is giving error.

```
      SELECT RowNum AS RowNumber1,
      GR.*,
      --LEVEL AS LineageLvl,
      VDE.*
    FROM
      (SELECT *
      FROM group_relations  left outer join relation_classifier_instances RC on 
      rc.relation_id = group_relations.Group_relation_id  WHERE group_relation_type_id IN
      (19,20,32,38,42,43)  and (rc.relation_id is null) 
      ) GR
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendor_Feed_data_elements VDE
    ON GR.Group_Relation_Type_Id = 19
    AND GR.Primary_GroupField_Id = VDE.Vendor_Data_Element_Id
      /* Code which is giving the error
      START WITH
      (
        VDE.Vendor_Data_Element_Id IS NOT NULL  )
      CONNECT BY nocycle prior GR.RELATED_GROUPFIELD_ID = GR.PRIMARY_GROUPFIELD_ID*/
```

Comment: what do your DBAs say?  Fairly sure an ora 600 is something that may need Oracle support to flesh out.

Comment: If you print the SQL statement you've generated (i.e. `dbms_output.put_line( dynSqlComplete )` before opening the cursor and then try to execute that statement manually, does the statement work?  If so, then you've narrowed the problem down to the call to `OPEN`.  If not, the problem is in the SQL statement itself or the SQL statement that you're generating is malformed.

Comment: @Justin, I have tried dbms_output.put_line( dynSqlComplete), in fact i tried dbms_output.put_line( 'hi' ) just before assigning the large query but it is not displaying. I think it is failing before that only. but when i reduce the varchar2 size and then execute, it is displaying "hi" and then character string buffer error is coming.

Comment: @tbone, i dont hv a DBA in my project. :(

Comment: What tool are you using?  In SQL*Plus, for example, you need to `set serveroutput on` in order to tell SQL*Plus to create a buffer for `dbms_output` to write to and to read from the buffer and display the data.  If you can't even print the word "hi", it implies that your tool hasn't been configured to display the output of `dbms_output`.  You could also write the SQL statement to a database table and view the query after your code runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a clob a CLOB in 11g, something like (untested):

```
declare
  l_sql clob;
  l_str1 varchar2(32767);
  l_str2 varchar2(32767);
begin
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_sql, false);

  l_str1 := 'some large SQL chunk';
  l_str2 := 'and the rest of large SQL chunk';

  l_sql := l_str1;
  dbms_lob.writeappend(l_sql, length(l_str2), l_str2);

  execute immediate l_sql;

  dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_sql);

end;
```

Comment: No can do, execute immediate takes varchar2, a clob results in `PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type`.

Comment: Unless that has changed between between 10gR2 and 11g.

Comment: @tbone, will give it a shot and let u kw. Thanks.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance - yes, it is something which changed in 11g : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#i33888

Comment: @ShannonSeverance its a new feature for 11g, it actually saved me in a similar situation (DW project) where I needed to dynamically create a table with many partitions.  I was also used to the 10g varchar restriction, but was happily surprised for 11g.

Answer (score -1):

Sure you don't want a function?  Here's an example of something I made that's similar.

```
FUNCTION showbody(cust varchar2, receipt varchar2) 
    RETURN sys_refcursor AS retval sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN retval FOR
        SELECT * 
        FROM comp.comp_remittance_details
        WHERE receipt_number=receipt 
            AND customer_number=cust;
    RETURN(retval);
END showbody;
```