# taking back up of DB- object procedure and reexecuting

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

how to take back up of a DB object and re execute the object.

now trying to do :taking back up using dbms_metadata and storing the definition in table as clob and using dynamic execution(execute immediate).
issue: dynamic execution is not accepting definition more than 32k characters.

Comment: Use DBMS_SQL. There are overloads with CLOB. Or use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689421/oracle-how-to-handle-32k-string-length-in-variables

Comment: what object definition do you have that is more than 32k long? That's a big thing.

Comment: procedures objects